# LockScreen SetImageUri error in scheduled agent WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to set an image as lockscreen background in a scheduled agent. When I call the method to set the image I see this error:

```
System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
   at Windows.Phone.System.UserProfile.LockScreen.SetImageUri(Uri value)
   at LockImagesAgent.ScheduledAgent.<OnInvoke>d__2.MoveNext()}
```

[image]

The code:

```
LockScreen.SetImageUri(new Uri("ms-appdata:///Local/img_Test.jpg", UriKind.Absolute));
```

The image was copied to the local store of the phone (local storage) and I've set the values in the app manifest file: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206968%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

**EDIT**: The code is not working with this image in particular, it's working with other images with lower resolution.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyoneone with the same issue: This error ocurred because the image was edited with some app and some filters were added to it. So the SO does not recognize the image as a valid one. Hope this helps ;)

**EDIT**: The true reason of this error was I was calling de SaveJpeg method with a percentage of quality of 100 and that's not correct. I am setting now the 85% and everything works ok.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Screen.SetImageUri(new Uri("ms-appx:///Local/img_Test.jpg", UriKind.Absolute));
```

I think you have confused to choose between `ms-appx` and `ms-appdata`

Comment: But that Uri is for app resources: ms-appdata points to the root of the local app data folder. ms-appx points to the Local app install folder, to reference resources bundled in the XAP package. Taken from documentation.

Comment: but here you would be needed the path for that image that is ms-appx points to the Local app install folder and your Local folder, to reference that image bundled in the XAP package.

Comment: Edited the question, the image was copied previously to the local storage, sorry for the mistake... is not part of the XAP package.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to check **Prevent deployment to SD cards** option in **WMAppManifest.xml** file.

To set an image as background through an app, that app needs to be **on phone** and **not SD card**.

Hope this helps.